# How to add a view on uinavigationcontroller covering navigation bar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation based application. I want to add an image covering the entire screen. If i add it on top of a pushed view controller it won't cover the navigation bar. How to solve it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use `[self presentModalViewController: animated:];` So wrapp your UIImage into a `UIViewController` and present it. It will display it in full screen.